# Kerning with xcolor

Tags: color, kerning

My question, in variants, I saw, asked many times here, but I can't solve problem.
If we use `\textcolor{FirstLetter}SecondAndOtherLettersOfWord`, we lost font kerning between first and second letters.
With `\showoutput` in log we have `\special{color push rgb 1 0 0}` and `\special{color pop}` instructions.
How we need combine `\bgroup`, `\egroup`, etc. (from previously answers) in this case (usual text, and often colorized only first letter in word)?

**XeLateX**. Can't use luacolor and LuaLatex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{V}AR

VAR
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't.  The `\special` nodes interrupt kerning.  Only LuaTeX can apply per-glyph colouring, which doesn't disrupt kerning (see the `luacolor` package)

Comment: xelatex inserts specials and so destroys kerning. This is a hard fact. So either accept the missing kerning or switch to lualatex.

Comment: Or write kenrnig table by hand, using \@ifnextchar...

Answer (score 5):

Measure the kerning between the word parts. I've added support also for something before the coloring.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\kerncolor}[4]{%
  % #1 = color, #2 = before, #3 = colored part, #4 = after
  \sbox0{#2#3}\sbox2{\mbox{#2}\mbox{#3}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  \sbox0{#3#4}\sbox2{\mbox{#3}\mbox{#4}}%
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  #2\kern\dimen0 \textcolor{#1}{#3}\kern\dimen2 #4%
}

\begin{document}

\kerncolor{red}{}{V}{AR}

VAR

\sbox0{\kerncolor{red}{}{V}{AR}}\the\wd0

\sbox0{VAR}\the\wd0

\itshape

\kerncolor{red}{}{V}{AR}

VAR

\sbox0{\kerncolor{red}{}{V}{AR}}\the\wd0

\sbox0{VAR}\the\wd0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! And it impossible #3 and #4 to unite in one - tokenize first letter?

Comment: @Elisey The main problem are accented letters.

Comment: Yes, but there is packet churchslavonic (I use it) and it have macros \cu@tokenizeletter - it considers all accents for first letter (for church slavonic language). I'll try combine your answer and this tokenizer. Thank you!