# Macros as argument for pgf parser

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color, kerning

**As continuation for answer on this question:** [Kerning with xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567220/kerning-with-xcolor)

There is first attempting define kerning macros for whole word with colored first letter, without parenthesis:
(in more programmer-style than TeX-style, using **pgf parser**). I set only several accents for first time.
(This macros I use for church-slavonic language)

And I don't know how use macros as argument in this case:
`\cuParse \SomeMacros` don't work correctly, m.b. whole argument-macros treat as first letter?
Anybody help with this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

% from egreg's answer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567220/kerning-with-xcolor
\newcommand{\kerncolor}[4]{%
  % #1 = color, #2 = before, #3 = colored part, #4 = after
  \sbox0{#2#3}\sbox2{\mbox{#2}\mbox{#3}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  \sbox0{#3#4}\sbox2{\mbox{#3}\mbox{#4}}%
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  #2\kern\dimen0 \textcolor{#1}{#3}\kern\dimen2 #4%
}
%------------------------------------------
\def\cuFirstLetter{}
\def\cuFirstSub{}
\def\cuSndSub{}
\def\cuSndLetter{}
\def\cuTail{}
\def\TailFinal{}

\futurelet\pgfspace{ }
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{initial}{%
  \edef\cuFirstLetter{\pgfparserletter}%
  \pgfparserswitch{second symbol}}
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{second symbol}{%
  \edef\cuSndLetter{\pgfparserletter}%
  \pgfparserswitch{letters}}
\newcommand{\SetCUWFirstCuAccent}[1]{%
  \pgfparserdef{cuw}{second symbol}{the letter #1}{%
    \edef\cuFirstSub{#1}%
    \pgfparserswitch{subs}}}
%Some general accents
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̀}% COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300) /вария
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{́}% COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301) /оксия 
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̈}% Combining Diaeresis (U+0308)
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̋}% Combining Double Acute Accent (U+030B)
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̏}% Combining Double Grave Accent (U+030F)
%Some church-slavonic accents:    
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{҃}% Combining Cyrillic Titlo (U+0483) /титло 
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{҆}% Combining Cyrillic Psili Pneumata (U+0486) /звательце
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{ⷭ}% с под покрытие
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{ⷣ}% д-титло 
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdef{cuw}{subs}{\meaning\pgfspace}{%
  \edef\TailFinal{\ }
  \pgfparserswitch{final}}
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{subs}{%
  \edef\cuSndLetter{\pgfparserletter}%
  \pgfparserswitch{letters}}
\newcommand{\SetCUWSecondCuAccent}[1]{%
  \pgfparserdef{cuw}{subs}{the letter #1}{%
    \edef\cuSndSub{#1}}}
%Some general accents
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{́}% COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301) /оксия
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{̀}% COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300) /вария 
%Some church-slavonic accents:
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{҇}% Combining Cyrillic Pokrytie (U+0487) /покрытие
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{letters}{%
  \let\savedTail\cuTail%
  \edef\cuTail{\savedTail\pgfparserletter}}
\pgfparserdef{cuw}{letters}{\meaning\pgfspace}{%
  \edef\TailFinal{\ }
  \pgfparserswitch{final}}
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdeffinal{cuw}{\kerncolor{red}{}{\cuFirstLetter\cuFirstSub\cuSndSub}{\cuSndLetter}\cuTail\TailFinal}%
\pgfparserset{cuw/silent=true}%
%------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\cuParse}[1]{%
  \def\cuFirstLetter{}%
  \def\cuFirstSub{}%
  \def\cuSndSub{}%
  \def\cuSndLetter{}%
  \def\cuTail{}%
  \def\cuTailFinal{}%
  \pgfparserparse{cuw}#1%
}

\newcommand{\TEST}{VAR}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Á}VE <- \textit{without kerning}

\cuParse ÁVE 

\cuParse ÀVE

\cuParse Ä́h

\cuParse \TEST test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This reminds me that the documentation of `\pgfparserreinsert` should be improved to make it clear that the contents of `\pgfparserletter` get reinserted...

Answer (score 2):

The following changes your code such that for the initial state of your parser it is checked whether the first token is a macro that doesn't take an argument. If that is the case that macro is expanded and the result stored into `\pgfparserletter`, the contents of which get reinserted by `\pgfparserreinsert`.

This way the first token will be expanded and the result examined by the parser. The test for a macro without a parameter will fail if the first token is a macro that includes `macro:->` in its replacement (that seems unlikely, so the test should be fine, but one could create a more robust test).

The only things changed from your original code is the added `\CuIfMacro` and `\CuIfMacroHelper` (which does the test), and the changed definition of `\pgfparserunknown{cuw}{initial}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

% from egreg's answer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567220/kerning-with-xcolor
\newcommand{\kerncolor}[4]{%
  % #1 = color, #2 = before, #3 = colored part, #4 = after
  \sbox0{#2#3}\sbox2{\mbox{#2}\mbox{#3}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  \sbox0{#3#4}\sbox2{\mbox{#3}\mbox{#4}}%
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  #2\kern\dimen0 \textcolor{#1}{#3}\kern\dimen2 #4%
}
%------------------------------------------
\def\cuFirstLetter{}
\def\cuFirstSub{}
\def\cuSndSub{}
\def\cuSndLetter{}
\def\cuTail{}
\def\TailFinal{}

\futurelet\pgfspace{ }
\makeatletter
\edef\CuIfMacro
  {%
    \unexpanded{\expandafter\CuIfMacroHelper\meaning\pgfparsertoken}%
    \unexpanded{\CuMark\@firstoftwo}%
    \detokenize{macro:->}%
    \unexpanded{\CuMark\@secondoftwo\CuStop}%
  }
\edef\CuIfMacroHelper{\unexpanded{\def\CuIfMacroHelper#1}\detokenize{macro:->}}%
\CuIfMacroHelper#2\CuMark#3#4\CuStop{#3}%
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{initial}{%
  \CuIfMacro
    {%
      \edef\pgfparserletter
        {\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfparserletter}}%
      \pgfparserreinsert
    }%
    {\edef\cuFirstLetter{\pgfparserletter}\pgfparserswitch{second symbol}}%
  }
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{second symbol}{%
  \edef\cuSndLetter{\pgfparserletter}%
  \pgfparserswitch{letters}}
\newcommand{\SetCUWFirstCuAccent}[1]{%
  \pgfparserdef{cuw}{second symbol}{the letter #1}{%
    \edef\cuFirstSub{#1}%
    \pgfparserswitch{subs}}}
%Some general accents
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̀}% COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300) /вария
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{́}% COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301) /оксия 
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̈}% Combining Diaeresis (U+0308)
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̋}% Combining Double Acute Accent (U+030B)
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{̏}% Combining Double Grave Accent (U+030F)
%Some church-slavonic accents:    
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{҃}% Combining Cyrillic Titlo (U+0483) /титло 
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{҆}% Combining Cyrillic Psili Pneumata (U+0486) /звательце
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{ⷭ}% с под покрытие
\SetCUWFirstCuAccent{ⷣ}% д-титло 
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdef{cuw}{subs}{\meaning\pgfspace}{%
  \edef\TailFinal{\ }
  \pgfparserswitch{final}}
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{subs}{%
  \edef\cuSndLetter{\pgfparserletter}%
  \pgfparserswitch{letters}}
\newcommand{\SetCUWSecondCuAccent}[1]{%
  \pgfparserdef{cuw}{subs}{the letter #1}{%
    \edef\cuSndSub{#1}}}
%Some general accents
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{́}% COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301) /оксия
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{̀}% COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300) /вария 
%Some church-slavonic accents:
\SetCUWSecondCuAccent{҇}% Combining Cyrillic Pokrytie (U+0487) /покрытие
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdefunknown{cuw}{letters}{%
  \let\savedTail\cuTail%
  \edef\cuTail{\savedTail\pgfparserletter}}
\pgfparserdef{cuw}{letters}{\meaning\pgfspace}{%
  \edef\TailFinal{\ }
  \pgfparserswitch{final}}
%------------------------------------------
\pgfparserdeffinal{cuw}{\kerncolor{red}{}{\cuFirstLetter\cuFirstSub\cuSndSub}{\cuSndLetter}\cuTail\TailFinal}%
\pgfparserset{cuw/silent=true}%
%------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\cuParse}[1]{%
  \def\cuFirstLetter{}%
  \def\cuFirstSub{}%
  \def\cuSndSub{}%
  \def\cuSndLetter{}%
  \def\cuTail{}%
  \def\cuTailFinal{}%
  \pgfparserparse{cuw}#1%
}

\newcommand{\TEST}{VAR}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Á}VE <- \textit{without kerning}

\cuParse ÁVE 

\cuParse ÀVE

\cuParse Ä́h

\cuParse \TEST test 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you help with space in last string (with macro) between **VAR** and **test**?

Comment: @Elisey That space doesn't exist as far as TeX is concerned, and automatically adding it could again result in unwanted behaviour. My suggestion would be to not use a space as the end delimiter of your parser, but instead let `\cuParse` take an argument and placing some other token (e.g., `\cuParse` itself) as the end token, then doing a `\pgfparserdef{cuw}{all}\cuParse{\pgfparserswitch{final}}`.

Comment: @Elisey and your parser would also work for `\cuParse\TEST\ test` there (though the `\ ` doesn't end the parser, but still gets output as a space, the parser would then be ended by the space after `test`).

Comment: Macro \cuParse can be end token? Thank you! (In similar case i insert into handler macros something non-text string like ==END==) - there is few info in pgf-documentation about this.

Comment: @Elisey everything can be used as an end token by using `\pgfparserswitch{final}`, you just have to know its `\meaning` (and make sure that it doesn't change). Feel free to make suggestions on how the documentation of `pgfparser` could be improved.