# Kerning when coloring single letters

Tags: color, kerning

When I manually colorize the capitals of words the kerning breaks. Is there a way to preserve this without manually adding in negative spaces?

[image: The error]

```
{\color{red}W}{onder}

Wonder
```

Comment: Please use “real” sample code instead of external images. Nobody wants to retype your code to reproduce your results.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358496/obtain-the-same-kerning-after-coloring-as-without-coloring-in-math-mode and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567220/kerning-with-xcolor/567224

Comment: Does this answer your question? [obtain the same kerning after coloring as without coloring in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358496/obtain-the-same-kerning-after-coloring-as-without-coloring-in-math-mode)

Comment: @mico I retracted the vote accordingly

Answer (score 11):

Compiling your document with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX and loading the [luacolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacolor) package solves the kerning issue.

If you need to load the `xcolor` package as well, you should load `xcolor` *before* `luacolor`. E.g., if you need to load `xcolor` with the option `table`, you should run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before running `\usepackage{luacolor}`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb+{\color{red}W}onder+     & {\color{red}W}onder \\
  \verb+\textcolor{red}{W}onder+ & \textcolor{red}{W}onder \\
  \verb+Wonder+                  & Wonder \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```